# Emitting event from socketIo python

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, chat, real-time

I'm stuck in development of socket.io with Python. I'm using this [lib](http://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I got a chat app running by using [this](https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-demo) android part and with the lib sample. I want to trigger an event from the server side from a separate file. Here's my code.

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template

sio = socketio.Server(logger=True, async_handlers= True)
app = Flask(__name__)

eventlet.monkey_patch()

@sio.on('connect', namespace='/d')
def connect(sid, environ):
   print('connect ', sid)
   pass

@sio.on('messaget', namespace='/d')
def messaget(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)
    # sio.emit('messaget', data, namespace='/d')
    # sendmsg("YO YO")

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/d')
def disconnect(sid):
   print('disconnect ', sid)

def start_socket(app):
   # wrap Flask application with socketio's middleware
   app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
   eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)

def sendmsg(data):
    my_data= { 'text': data };
    sio.emit('messaget', my_data, namespace='/d')

start_socket(app)
```

I'm calling `sendmsg("dipen")` from my another python file. I'm getting a log **emitting event "messaget" to all [/d]** but android app is not getting any messages. And it work's if event is emitting from the Android app. I tried with the NodeJs code and it worked for the NodeJs code so I'm pretty sure that something is wrong in my Python code. Hope that someone could save me from this.

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions of your client code?

Comment: @Miguel I'm using sample from this link - https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-server-demo/blob/master/index.js

Comment: You pointed me at a JavaScript client code. Didn't you say you have problems with an Android client?

Comment: @Miguel Sorry for that, it was a link for NodeJs code. Please refer this - https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-demo

Comment: Your server above uses a `/d` namespace. Can you point me to where in the Android application this namespace is declared or used?

Comment: @miguel I have updated the android code to use namespace. I don't think that's an issue. I have tried this - https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py example. When I use this code in a single file, it works perfectly. But when I try to call this background_thread from my another file with cherryPy application, it will print a log 'emitting event "my response" to all [/d]' but @ client side webpage or android client won't be able to get that event.

Comment: I don't see any updates in the Android code you linked. I'm sorry, but I can't really help you if you don't show me the exact code you are running, for both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message from Android client. Does your Python code get it? If not, check if you have connected to the same namespace.

Comment: Yes it gets the message and I can also emit an event from that thread. But it's not working from the separate thread (file)